# convert hexadecimal number to binary

Tags: java

```
int hex=Integer.parseInt(str.trim(),16);
String binary=Integer.toBinaryString(hex);
```

i have a array of hexadecimal numbers as strings and i want to convert those numbers to binary string, above is the code i used and in there, i get a error as shown below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "e24dd004"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at sew1.javascript.main(javascript.java:20)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximum Integer in Java is `0x7fffffff`, because it is signed.

Use

```
Long.parseLong(str.trim(),16);
```

or

```
BigInteger(str.trim(),16);
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `e24dd004` is larger than `int` can handle in Java. If you use `long`, it will be fine:

```
String str = "e24dd004";
long hex = Long.parseLong(str.trim(),16);
String binary=Long.toBinaryString(hex);
System.out.println(binary);
```

That will be valid for hex up to 7fffffffffffffff.

An alternative, however, would be to do a direct conversion of each hex digit to 4 binary digits, without ever converting to a numeric value. One simple way of doing that would be to have a `Map<Character, String>` where each string is 4 digits. That will potentially leave you with leading 0s of course.

Comment: thnx for helping its k now

Answer (score 0):

Use BigInteger as below:

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("e24dd004", 16);
String binary = bigInteger.toString(2);
```

Or using `Long.toBinaryString()` as below:

```
long longs = Long.parseLong("e24dd004",16);
String binary = Long.toBinaryString(longs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you can treat integers as unsigned, so you could do:

```
String str = "e24dd004";
int i = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(str, 16);
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(i); //11100010010011011101000000000100
String backToHex = Integer.toUnsignedString(i, 16); //e24dd004
```

You would be able to handle values that are not larger than `2^32-1` (instead of `2^31-1` if you use signed values).
If you can't use it, you'll have to parse it as a long like other answers showed.